# requiring Angular with Browserify. 'Uncaught object' error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browserify

When I require the Angular library with Browserify, I get an 'Uncaught object' error in bundle.js. It seems like Browserify has a problem with the Angular library? All other required files work with no errors. Can someone help me solve this please?

In my index.js file I do this 'require('./angular');' Which works as expected and bundles the file. Below are screenshots of the console errors.

[image]
[image: From Console]

Comment: angular is not CommonJS (or AMD for that matter).  To `require` it with browserify you'd have to shim it.  Personally I've found this combo to be such a PITA that I just load angular normally and use the global variable within browserify modules.

Comment: Could you try `require`ing Angular from some other file (say, `common.js`) and then requiring `common.js` in your angular module file?
I'm not sure if this is the reason my app is working, but it very well could be. Here's my `common` file: https://github.com/prajwalkman/magrathea/blob/master/frontend/src/common.coffee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browserify is not your issue in this case. There is a misconception that you cannot use libraries with Browserify without shims.  Actually you can.  I use both Angular, and Angular-Route fetched via Bower with Browserify just fine.

The **uncaught object** is an AngularJS error. More than likely due to incorrect dependancy loading.  Several mentions with NgRoute on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921769/angularjs-ngroute-uncaught-object-error), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898348/angular-application-config-uncaught-object-error-ngroute), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898113/uncaught-object-error-on-chrome-angularjs-ngresource)

Comment: You are right. This was really careless of me. Browserify works fine with Angular. The problem was that I had misnamed my main app controller. The message wasn't descriptive so I assumed it was a Browserify issue.

Comment: The generic "uncaught object" error message will hopefully be soon behind us. This is a combination of when Angular introduced ngMinErr (robust error message utility) under the hood starting in 1.2.x, and a Chrome bug that made its way into the #stable branch.  A fix in recent version of Chrome Canary will show the error messages as intended.